# How to load a url in swift

Tags: swift, http-post, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I need to load a url to delete a playlist in my music app.  I don't need to pull any data from it, just load it.  Basically, if I copy and paste the url into the browser, the API knows to delete the specified playlist.

Here's what I have so far:

```
func deletePlaylist(id: String, token: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let url = "app.com/api.php?m=delete_playlist&pid=\(id)&token=\(token)"
    })
}
```

I've tried NSURLConnect, NSURLSession, etc. but nothing is working.  How do I just load the url as if it were pasted into a web browser?

Comment: You forgot the url scheme. Your browser  works without it but you need to include it to create a web NSURL

Comment: I feel dumb.  Formatting the url properly would have saved me so much time.  Thanks!